# How do I left-justify the date in document class letter?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles, letters

Really basic question, but I'm having trouble finding documentation.  How can I left-justify the date in `\documentclass{letter}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date is set under `\raggedleft` by default, forcing it to be flush-right with the text block. This forms part of the `\opening` command which would have to be redefined to suit your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{letter}

\signature{First last name}
\address{First last name \\ Street name \\ City \\ Country}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\opening}[1]{\ifx\@empty\fromaddress
  \thispagestyle{firstpage}%
    {\raggedleft\@date\par}%
  \else  % home address
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    {\raggedleft\begin{tabular}{l@{}}\ignorespaces
      \fromaddress \\*[2\parskip]%
      \end{tabular}\par
     \raggedright\@date\par}%
  \fi
  \vspace{2\parskip}%
  {\raggedright \toname \\ \toaddress \par}%
  \vspace{2\parskip}%
  #1\par\nobreak}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Something \\ That \\ Is \\ Important}
\opening{Dear Who Cares}

Can you help me move the sender's address to the left? It is too close to the right edge. I would like to make sure that it does not go more to the right than does the text in the body of the letter.

\closing{Sincerely,}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Regardless, for regular letters I'd advise against using the `letter` class, as you can very comfortably set a letter in the default `article` class.

Comment: What is the problem with the `letter` class?

Comment: @user1521655: For one, ordinary classes in general restrict you to a context, while packages are meant to extend that restriction. I find that there's very little incentive for the restriction when writing a letter. As you saw, there's no mention of it in the documentation, and what kind of manipulation do you need to do if you want to switch other things around; similar, complete redefinitions of patches. Secondly, I find the order of the commands to be weird. Why define `\signature` in the preamble and not with `\closing` as it is would logically group better that way... strange.