# How can I move the date from right (default) to left side in a letter in LaTeX?

Tags: loops, code, letters

I wanted to prepare a cover letter for which I downloaded a template from an online website. The LaTeX code is as follows. By default, the date appears to be in right top. How do I bring it to the left? I am new to LaTeX and any help on this would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\oddsidemargin=.2in
\evensidemargin=.2in
\textwidth=5.9in
\topmargin=-.5in
\textheight=9in


\newcommand {\qed}{\mbox{$\Box$}}
\renewcommand {\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
\newcommand {\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand {\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand {\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand {\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}

\newcommand {\sub}{\mbox{SB}}


\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Mathematics Search Committee\\
Department of Mathematics\\
University of Somewhere\\
1234 Math Building
Somewhere, IL, 23456}


\opening{Dear Search Committee,}

My research interests include continuous logic and its application to metric structures from analysis and geometry. My thesis work is on the model theory of $\R$-trees, which are metric spaces of central importance in geometric group theory. I am currently finishing a paper with my advisor, and expect at least one more paper to result from the contents of my thesis.

\closing{Sincerely, }
Sylvia Carlisle\\
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello does http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/334687/124842 works for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to just flush the date to the left by redefining `\date`, or actually `\@date`. (It requites that this is the only place `\@date`is used.)

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\oddsidemargin=.2in
\evensidemargin=.2in
\textwidth=5.9in
\topmargin=-.5in
\textheight=9in


\newcommand {\qed}{\mbox{$\Box$}}
\renewcommand {\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
\newcommand {\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand {\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand {\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand {\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}

\newcommand {\sub}{\mbox{SB}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%% New stuff
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\date[1]{\gdef\@date{\hbox to \linewidth{#1\hss}}}
\makeatother
\date{\today}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Mathematics Search Committee\\
Department of Mathematics\\
University of Somewhere\\
1234 Math Building
Somewhere, IL, 23456}


\opening{Dear Search Committee,}

My research interests include continuous logic and its application to metric structures from analysis and geometry. My thesis work is on the model theory of $\R$-trees, which are metric spaces of central importance in geometric group theory. I am currently finishing a paper with my advisor, and expect at least one more paper to result from the contents of my thesis.

\closing{Sincerely, }
Sylvia Carlisle\\
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
\date{\begin{flushleft}\today\end{flushleft}}
```

below your `\begin{document}`

Hope this helps!

Comment: While this works in this case, it is a bad idea to add such formatting in the argument to `\date`; in other styles this may not work at all and only pure text is expected here.  It is better to adjust the underlying formatting instructions, such as `https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/334687/15925`, or find a new class that provides appropriate options.